# To access javascript files from another app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, apache, assets, precompile

I'm trying to access to my pre-compiled files of my application from another. I've a specific architecture. Here is a simplified tree

```
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   │   ├── application.coffee
│   │   │   ├── my_js_file.coffee
├── my-other-app
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── javascript
│   │   ├── anotherJSFile.js
```

I would like to load on `index.html` the compiled file of `my_js_file.coffee`.

`my-other-app` isn't a Rails app. It contains a basic `index.html` file where a specific URL redirect where I try something like:

```
<script src="http://myapp.com/assets/my_js_file.js"></script>
```

I've defined it on an `Apache` configuration file (this part is ok).

My problem is that I can't find any way to access to a compiled `my_js_file.js` file. The access to the file and the file name itself (with fingerprint). How could I solve this?

**Edit:**
**I think the main problem comes from the fingerprint because I need to know it to adapt my url on my second app dynamically.**

**Edit2:**
**I've found a way to generate dynamic url with correct fingerprint but I still can't access to compiled files (unauthorized)**

Comment: Are you sure the url to the other file works?  Try putting the url (`http://myapp.com/assets/my_js_file.js`) into the address bar of your browser.  If that seems to work then it's odd that the first app can't see it.  I would use the network tab in chrome dev tools to debug that.

Comment: no it's not because in production I need to know the fingerprint.. And I don't know how to get this fingerprint to change my url according to it.

Comment: You need to talk more about this fingerprint in your question, since that's clearly the cause of the issue.

Comment: I've added some details.

Comment: Do you even need fingerprints?

Comment: I think so because if I don't have it, I can't call it from outside my second app.

Comment: I've found a way to generate url with fingerprint but I still can't access to my script (unauthorized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it but it was a bit tricky.

There are 2 points :

1. js fingerprint
2. authentification token from the rails app to the other webpage (outside this rails app environment)

To solve the first point I had to create a method on a model that I call at the end of a deployment (with `capistrano`) to modify my `index.html` file dynamically. Here is how I did it:

```
#my-other-app/index.html

<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <!-- BEGIN DYNAMIC URI -->

        <!-- END DYNAMIC URI -->

    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="awesome">
            Some stuff here..
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
#myModel.rb
def self.generate_index_file
  js_files = ['my_js_file.js']
  tempfile = File.open Rails.root.join('my-other-app/index.tmp'), 'w'
  f = File.new('my-other-app/index.html')
  f.each do |line|
    if line =~ /^.*<!-- BEGIN DYNAMIC URI -->/
      tempfile << line
      js_files.each do |filename|
        fingerprinted_name = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(filename).digest_path
        tempfile << "<script src='#{Rails.application.default_url_options[:host]}/assets/" + fingerprinted_name + "?body=1'></script>\n"
      end

    else
      tempfile << line
    end
  end

  f.close       
  tempfile.close

  FileUtils.mv("my-other-app/index.tmp", "my-other-app/index.html")
end
```

---

```
#config/deploy/production.rb
# Available only for Capistrano 2.x

namespace :deploy do
  task :generate_samsung_index, roles: :app do
    run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rails runner 'MyModel.generate_index_file'}
  end 
end
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:generate_samsung_index"
```

Now, to solve the second part of the problem (authentification part), I needed to add token to the url before adding it to the `<head>`. Here is my code:

```
#my_models_controller.rb
def my_method
  redirect_to "http://myawesomeurl.com?token=#{form_authenticity_token}"
end
```

---

```
#my-other-app/index.html
# On <head> with my previous code
<script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript">
   meta1 = document.createElement("meta");
   meta1.name = "csrf-param";
   meta1.content = "authenticity_token";
   $("head").append(meta1);

   token = "token"
   token_result = new RegExp(token + '=([^&]*)', 'i').exec(window.location.search)
   meta2 = document.createElement("meta");
   meta2.name = "csrf-param";
   meta2.content = token_result;

   $("head").append(meta1);
   $("head").append(meta2);
 </script>
```

I hope this will help someone else.