# Get the asset url without fingerprint in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Using `javascript_url` we can get the url of the asset:

```
&lt;script src="<%= javascript_url 'company_widget' %>"
  token="<%= current_user.token %>"
  class="ofri-company-widget"
&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

However, the `javascript_url` returns the url with the fingerprint:

```
domain.com/assets/company_widget-<fingerprint>.js
```

It seems this get cached forever, and whenever we need to make changes in the script, the third-parties using this script will have to reload it.

I noticed that accessing the file without fingerprint works too:

```
domain.com/assets/company_widget.js
```

Is there a way to tell `javascript_url` to not add the fingerprint? Or is there another better solution in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need to do is to return your javascript file in controller action, so have control over the cache for this particular file.

In your controller action you should do something like:

```
def company_widget
  response.headers["Expires"] = 1.day.from_now.httpdate
  expires_in 1.day, public: true, must_revalidate: true

  format.js do
    asset = open(ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url('company_widget.js', host: host))
    send_data asset.read, :type => asset.content_type
  end
end

def host
  request.protocol + request.host_with_port
end
```

Then you can point to controller action and be sure that you have control over what is returned.

```
<script src="http://example.com/company_widget.js"></script>
```

`Expires` header is older way of setting cache, while `expires_in` Rails method will set `Cache-Control` header which is the best way to manage your cache. It takes precedence over `Expires`.

Additionally you can take a look on a great article about caching: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Answer (score 2):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-digests-off

You can turn off digests by updating config/environments/development.rb to include:

`config.assets.digest = false`

Comment: Won't this turn off all the digests? What I really want is to replace `javascript_url 'company_widget'` with something which will resolve to the same url, but without the hash. For instance, I could remove the hash manually using string methods, but I'm just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: But without fingerprint, the browser will not update your new code until you remove the cache right? Your file doesn't change -> so your 3rd don't reload but also cannot get new change? Base on the docs: "This will cause the remote clients to request a new copy of the content.". Is there any reason make you want to handle it in rails side?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that at least it's not cached on the server, but in the browser. What do you think would be the best solution? Maybe adding a route which serves the file without caching (e.g. `domain.com/api/widget` → `assets/company_widget.js`)?

Comment: I have no idea with the solution, but I found this and I think it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048438/to-access-javascript-files-from-another-app